# django - sorting a model in the admin ui according to translated name

Tags: python, django, django-forms, django-templates

EDIT:
I've decided to change my question to this, in hope that a more general question will be more appealing...

so I have a model, it has a M2M field which is not translated in the server, but it is in the client side. Can I sort this field in the admin-ui, especially every time I add a new instance of the model?

This was my last attempt:

The models of interest are:

```
class Recipe(models.Model):
     name = models.CharField(max_length=200,verbose_name=_("name"))
     ingredient_list = models.ManyToManyField(IngredientType, through='Ingredient')

class IngredientType(models.Model):
     name = models.CharField(max_length=25)

class Ingredient(models.Model):
    ingredient_type =models.ForeignKey(IngredientType,verbose_name=_("IngredientType"))
    recipe = models.ForeignKey(Recipe)
```

recipe_admin.py:

```
class IngredientInline(admin.TabularInline):
    model = Ingredient
    extra = 1

class RecipeAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin): 
    inlines = [IngredientInline]
    form = RecipeForm

class RecipeForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
      model = Recipe
```

I've added a long list of IngredientType objects in my initial_data.json file.
Now, each time a person adds a new ingredient to his recipe, he selects an ingredient_type from the long drop-down list that opens up.

EDIT:
When looking at the form's html in the browser I have these lines for my drop-down list.
as you can see, underneath the field's  there's a line responsible for adding another row to the inline using the showAddAnotherPopup(this) function:
(I would like to somehow hook into that function, and every time it's called, to call my sorting function)

```
<select id="id_ingredient_set-0-ingredient_type" name="ingredient_set-0-ingredient_type">
<option value="" selected="selected">---------</option>
<option value="42">אבוקדו</option>
<option value="80">אבטיח</option>
....
</select>
<a href="/admin/vcb/ingredienttype/add/" class="add-another" id="add_id_ingredient_set-0-ingredient_type" onclick="return showAddAnotherPopup(this);"> <img src="/static/admin/img/icon_addlink.gif" width="10" height="10" alt="Add another"></a>
```

My problem is, that dynamically added Ingredient rows that the user adds to his recipe form, results in the drop-down ingredient_type names list to be unsorted. I am able to sort by the Hebrew alphabetical order, but i've managed to do so only for the lines already apparent when the page loads.

I've done the above by migrating the django's tabular.html file into my project file system, and adding some js that sorts it:

```
function sortAlpha(a,b){  
return a.innerHTML.toLowerCase() > b.innerHTML.toLowerCase() ? 1 : -1;  
};
```

and I'm calling it like so:

> ('#id_ingredient_set-0-ingredient_type option').sort(sortAlpha).appendTo('#id_ingredient_set-0-ingredient_type');

Inside the function that fires when the page is loaded. 
but this approach obviously does not deal with all dynamically added Ingredient rows that the user adds to his recipe form, that results in the drop-down ingredient_type names list to be unsorted. (It hooks on the present id in the )

This is django's showAddAnotherPopup method which I also added to my project's file system:

```
function showAddAnotherPopup(triggeringLink) {
   var name = triggeringLink.id.replace(/^add_/, '');
   name = id_to_windowname(name);
   href = triggeringLink.href
   if (href.indexOf('?') == -1) {
       href += '?_popup=1';
    } else {
       href  += '&_popup=1';
    }
   var win = window.open(href, name, 'height=500,width=800,resizable=yes,scrollbars=yes');
   win.focus();
   return false;
}
```

I'm a django noob, so I still lack knowledge in all the AJAX/js/templatetag buzz-words...
Help will be much appreciated.
tnx
Nitzan

Comment: if more info is missing i'll be happy to provide..

Answer (score 0):

It's not clear in your example how you are triggering the sort function on the initial page load, but it seems you need to call the function again after each new item is added. Add an onclick, onblur, or other event trigger to the ingredient addition method that will call your sorting function again.

If you are trying to order the displayed list of items as created by the modelform, you can use the meta options `order` or `order_with_respect_to`. See https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/options/#ordering for more info.

Comment: I can't use the order or order_with_respect_to options, because they use data on the db, while my ingredient_type are not translated there. As my EDIT implies, I understand I do need to add some onClick method, or to somehow override django's showAddAnotherPopup(this).

Comment: But I don't know how-to, hence my question..:)

Comment: Have you tried changing the onclick to a new function call that performs the showAddAnotherPopup(this), then the resortFunction() then return"?    
If the HTML is being created by the Django admin interface  hacking that can be very complicated as you have to creat your own overriding versions of the views.

Comment: No, because I don't know how to.. can you post an answer? also, i've edited the post, and added the showAddAnotherPopup(this) method.

Comment: Sorry I don't have a specific solution as I have hacked that part of the admin yet.  These links may give some inside. http://sontek.net/blog/detail/implementing-djangos-admin-interface-pop-ups  and http://www.hoboes.com/Mimsy/hacks/replicating-djangos-admin/.  Look at creating a custom function for handlePopupAdd.